# Store a particular set points in a new cell array

Tags: matlab

I had asked a similar question few weeks back but I think that question was not framed properly so please excuse me for asking the same question again

I have a column vector with values

32.5

25.8

25.91

25.92

16.52

16.7

Now I want to create a cell array such that my first cell contains the first value, my second cell array contains value from 25.8 to 25.92 and finally my third cell array contains the values 16.52 and 16.7 .

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: So you want values with the same integer part to be stored in the same cell?

Comment: Why nwould you partition into cell arrays? Would you be happy to have indices pointing at each grouping, such that you can select the group univocally in future calculations?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't explain why you want the vector split up, I assume the specified division is arbitrary.  The following should do what you want, assuming v is the column vector:

```
c = {v(1) v(2:4) v(5:6)};
```

Basically you are constructing three new vectors out of pieces of the original, and putting them together into a cell array.

Comment: these value in column are just for example. So for example after 32.8 I can get value which is 32.1 so it gets stored in same cell array. Similarly I may get 10 or 20 different values with 24.5 to 25.5 which again get stored in the same cell array.

Comment: Ok, what was missing in your question was the criterion for how to split the original vector into cells.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way with `for` loop.

```
A = [...
    32.5
    25.8
    25.91
    25.92
    16.52
    16.7];

[U,~,ic] = unique(floor(A));

B = cell(length(U),1); % Result

for k = 1:length(A)
    B{ic(k)} = [B{ic(k)} A(k)];
end
```

Thank to [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) command the result is even sorted.